# Update JSF in carusell

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I currently try to implement a website, where an dialog, opened from an carousel, changes something in the database and the result is shown on the screen. For that, I try to update an area in the dialog. Unfortunately, updating things in an carusell does not seem to work.

I shortened the code to an minimal example, so with the following code:

```
<p:carousel id="page" value="#{pagebean.pages}"
    var="item" numVisible="1">
    <h:form id="dlg_2_form">
        <h:outputText id="test_2" value="#{pagebean.value}" />
        <p:remoteCommand name="update_2" update="test_2" />
        <a href="#" onclick="update_2();"> Increment</a>
    </h:form>
</p:carousel>
```

the function `pagebean.value` is not called after I click on Increment, but therefore the constructor of `pagebean` is called when I click on Increment. So it seems like the carousel makes it impossible to update something in it.

Does anyone know, if there is an possibility to update something which is in a carousel, or if there is a workaround for this problem?

EDIT: After the discussion below, I know that Increment does work, if the scope of the corresponding bean is set to @ViewScoped. I could also trigger this button by giving it a widgetVar and accessing its click function, so this would work. Unfortunately, the Bean I want to use is SessionScoped, and with this kind of view it does not work. Has anybody an hint how to solve this problem? I could copy everything into a second Bean, which is ViewScoped, but this is not a very nice solution.

Comment: First, try changing the scope of your managed bean to `@ViewScoped` in order your bean keeps alive while the user is in the same view. Second, you should use `<p:commandLink>` instead of `<a>` where its `onclick` method calls a `<p:remoteCommand>`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried changing the Scope (it was `@SessionScoped` before), but that didn't change anything. Directly setting the text with the commandlink itself (with `<p:commandLink action="#{zuordnungsverwalter.value}" update="test_2">Increment</p:commandLink>`) did make the text change, but the remoteCommand stil does not change the text (whereas the exact same source outside the carousel does this).

Comment: The command from the commandlink and from the normal link are transformed into Javascript. I found out that the Javascript-Command that works is `PrimeFaces.ab({source:'page:0:dlg_2_form:j_idt17',update:'page:0:dlg_2_form:test_2');` and the Javascript-command that does not work is `PrimeFaces.ab({source:'page:0:dlg_2_form:j_idt16',formId:'page:0:dlg_2_form',update:'page:0:dlg_2_form:test_2',params:arguments[0]});}`. The second command failes in Javascript commandline because arguments is not defined - I got no clue why primeface has created this.

Comment: After all, I found the very first mistake (from a comment in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16967524/jsf-sessionscoped-bean-not-retaining-properties): the SessionScope annotation I used was from javax.enterprise.context, so it was realy request-scoped, the constructor was called everytime, the update got empty data (because of an empty carousel) and therefore it wasn't called.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem for starters when working with CDI and JSF in the same project.